# Inzu - IE 9 not recongising full height of menu item

Tags: html, css

A menu system for an Inzu site is not working in IE 9. Between each li element a "branch" graphic is generated in CSS to separate the li elements with a gap an small connector.

In all other browser including IE 11 the menu works fine but in IE 9 the menu disappears when the mouse is over the gap, running the mouse over the connector graphic is fine.

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="section_1"><a href='about.php?section=section_1&id=About'>About the BSCB</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href='page.php?section=section_1&id=266'>Structure and Governance</a></li>
<li><a href='page.php?section=section_1&id=265'>BSCB Membership</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.section_1{
  background-color: #a30046;
}

.nav {
  height: 47px;
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.nav li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 6px;
  width: 115px;
  min-height: 39px;
}
.nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 117px;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 39px;
}
.nav li .submenu li {
  width: 115px !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 45px;
}
.nav li .submenu li a {
  min-height: 39px;
}
.nav li .submenu li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

The connector is made with the last block, this can all be seen at http://www.bexleylscb.org.uk

Answer (score 0):

By setting the background of the list elements with a transparent PNG the problem went away.